# How to mock a protected method in base class using Rhino?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

```
internal abstract class ClassB: IInterface
{
    protected void Execute();
}

abstract class ClassA : ClassB
{
    public void methodToUT()
    {
        ---logic that I want to unit test----
        Execute();
    }
}
```

I want to unit test the `methodToUT()`. However I am not able to mock/stub `Execute()` using Rhino since it is Protected. I tried creating
a helper class that implements ClassB and overrode `Execute()` so that I can mock it. However, I then get the error
"Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method)."

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unit tests have a habit of exposing design issues. What does that method do? can it be refactored to be `virtual` so that it can be overridden in a derived class?

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests have a habit of exposing design issues.

If that member can be refactored to be `virtual` or `abstract`

```
abstract class ClassB: IInterface {
    protected virtual void Execute();
}
```

so that it can be overridden in a derived class then

a stub can be created

```
public class StubClass: ClassA {
    protected override void Execute() {
        //...Do nothing
    }
}
```

Otherwise you should be able to replace the desired member, with the `new` keyword, if unable to override it.

```
public class StubClass: ClassA {
    protected new void Execute() {
        //...Do nothing
    }
}
```

for the purpose of testing

```
//Arrange
var subject = new StubClass(); 

//Act
subject.methodToUT();

//...
```

Comment: I am afraid I cannot do that. I am using ClassB from a library that I cannot modify.

Comment: @PradeepVairamani are you able to refactor your code to use an adapter pattern? That way you do not tightly couple to code you have no control over?

Comment: I am not completely sure how I can do that. The StubClass equivalent was exactly what I did but then I got the error ""Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).""

Comment: @PradeepVairamani by manually creating the stub there was no need for RhinoMocks. You create an instance of the subject under test and exercise the test.

Comment: The problem with creating the instance of the subject using new keyword is that the base method is getting hidden but not overridden. It therefore still tries to call the Execute() of the base class.